# How can I remove a DevExpress appointment from a calendar during an event on that appointment?

Tags: c#, event-handling, devexpress

I have a DevExpress SchedulerControl with various Appointments in its SchedulerStorage. Under certain conditions an Appointment may become invalid due to changes made in another window or another instance of the application. When the appointment is dragged & dropped in the calendar window, I'd like to detect this & remove the appointment.

Here's a simplified version of the code I have now:

```
private void myScheduleControl_AppointmentDrop(object sender, AppointmentDragEventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsAppointmentValid(e.EditedAppointment))
   {
      // remove appointment here
      e.Handled = true;
      return;
   }

   // do other stuff
}
```

The problem is that when an invalid appointment is dropped, this code runs but the appointment still appears in the calendar. I've tried both `mySchedulerControl.DeleteAppoint(e.EditedAppointment)` and `mySchedulerStorage.Appointments.Remove(e.EditedAppointment)` between calls to `mySchedulerControl.SuspendLayout()` and `mySchedulerControl.ResumeLayout()`, without success.

My experience with DevExpress has been that often methods that would change or remove an object have no effect if called while an event on that object is being handled. How can I remove this one appointment without repopulating the entire ScheduleStorage?

Elsewhere I saw a suggestion to use `BeginInvoke()` to have things run once the event is finished. I haven't messed with invoking before now; if that's a valid approach, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per DevExpress Support, it's done more or less like this:

```
if (!IsAppointmentValid(e.EditedAppointment))
{
   BeginInvoke(new Action<SchedulerControl, Appointment>(
      delegate(SchedulerControl schdCtrl, Appointment appt)
      {
         schdCtrl.Storage.Appointments.Remove(appt);
      }), mySchedulerControl, e.SourceAppointment);

   e.Handled = true;
   return;
}
```

It's important to use `e.SourceAppointment` rather than `e.EditedAppointment` because `e.EditedAppointment` is a **clone** of the appointment that includes the changes, while `e.SourceAppointment` is the actual appointment that will be changed. Removing `e.EditedAppointment` has no effect since it's not in the appointments collection.

It's also necessary to do this in a `BeginInvoke()` call. After event handlers are done some additional processing is performed that looks for the appointment being dragged & dropped in the appointments collection. The collection will ignore requests to remove it during the event (even if you correctly ask it to remove `e.SourceAppointment`), and if you directly alter the appointments data source you'll get an unhandled exception in the DevExpress code after the event handler returns.